# How to get multi-line data from textarea to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to paste information from excel into a textarea that then splits it down into each field, however I want to also keep blank fields as not all of the fields will always have data.

The data im pasting is `13 columns (with some blank)` each separated with a tab and then on to a new line. The total number of rows changes daily from

```
1 - 100 EG:
Dr Pete    1234567890    anthony    woods    11/11/11    planned visit    12/12/12   dr roger    AMH    13/01/13   planned discharge    usual place of residence    "would be blank"
```

OR

```
Dr Pete    1234567890    anthony    woods    11/11/11    planned visit    12/12/12   dr roger    AMH    "would be blank"   "would be blank"    "would be blank"    "would be blank"
```

**html form:**

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php">
<textarea name="area"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**php insert.php:**

```
$area = preg_split("[\t]", "$textarea");

print_r($area);

$sql = "INSERT INTO admissions (registered_gp, nhs_no, forename, surname, dob, admission_method, admitted_on, consultant, ward, discharge_date, 
discharge_reason, discharged_to, date_of_death)
VALUES ('$area')";
```

I've gotten this far and got the following error **"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"** - I presume this is because I have listed 13 fields but only 1 value. How would I go about having enough values for each field including blanks.

I would presume I some how need to separate each line of data, then separate each column of data and give it it's own value name?

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code like this and try

```
$var = 'Dr Pete    1234567890    anthony    woods    11/11/11    planned visit    12/12/12   dr roger    AMH    13/01/13    planned discharge    usual place of residence    "would be blank"';

        $area = explode("    ", $var);

        $registered_gp = $area[0] ;
        $nhs_no = $area[1] ;
        $forename = $area[2] ;
        $surname = $area[3] ;
        $dob = $area[4] ;
        $admission_method = $area[5] ;
        $admitted_on = $area[6] ;
        $consultant = $area[7] ;
        $ward  = $area[8] ;
        $discharge_date = $area[9] ;
        $discharge_reason = $area[10] ;
        $discharged_to = $area[11] ;
        $date_of_death = $area[12] ;


        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO admissions (registered_gp, nhs_no, forename, surname, dob, admission_method, admitted_on, consultant, ward, discharge_date, 
discharge_reason, discharged_to, date_of_death)
VALUES ('$registered_gp','$nhs_no','$forename','$surname','$dob','$admission_method','$admitted_on','$consultant','$ward','$discharge_date','$discharge_reason','$discharged_to','$date_of_death')");
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, would this however work if its pulling data from a text area instead of preset data?

Comment: yes it will pull data from textarea please make sure u give separated with a tab between every single information 
Like 

$var = 'Dr Pete    1234567890    anthony    woods    11/11/11    planned visit    12/12/12   dr roger    AMH    "would be blank"   "would be blank"    "would be blank"    "would be blank"' ;

Comment: As soon as I put this code onto the page is get http error 500.

Comment: I have tried using you above code and I have become stuck again. The `$var = ####` bit I do not understand at all and doesn't seem to work. 
I am using `$area1 = preg_replace("[\t]", ',', $textarea);` & `$area = explode(",", $area1); `
This is then splitting the data into an array perfectly, Until I enter more than one line of data, then the final blank field is replaced with the first used field of the next line and becomes array[13] instead of going back to [0]??? Any Ideas? I have searched the web for 8 hours to find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

change the tabs by commas right before doing $sql=...

```
$area = str_replace("[\t]", "','", $area);
```

Comment: is this to be used with the above commented code or my original code?

Comment: Should it be:  $area = str_replace("[\t]", ",", $textarea);

Comment: in the php file, before inserting the var $area in the $sql string.

php insert.php:

`$area = str_replace("[\t]", "','", $area);

$sql = "INSERT INTO admissions (registered_gp, nhs_no, forename, surname, dob, admission_method, admitted_on, consultant, ward, discharge_date, 
discharge_reason, discharged_to, date_of_death)
VALUES ('$area')";
`